# Assign with nullptr and zero size

Tags: c++, stl

If I e.g. have a vector v, is it ok by the standard to call:

```
void setData(const uint8_t* p, size_t s) {
    v.assign(p, p+s);
}

setData(nullptr, 0);
```

In general is it always ok to call STL functions `XXX(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)`as above when `distance(first,last) == 0`?

Comment: +1. @WeaselFox not so fast. Are you sure the standard mandates that it  will not attempt a pointer or iterator dereference if the size is zero? We could be in UB-land here.

Comment: @Bathsheba The standard does seem to mandate exactly that, when it says that each iterator in [p, p+s) shall be dereferenced exactly once. The only argument you could make is that that *doesn't* say that iterators outside of [p, p+s) shall not be dereferenced, but that's just like how it doesn't say `v.assign` shall not randomly output `Boo!`.

Comment: @hvd: Great comment. Why not make an answer? I'll be sure to upvote it, and I think the OP should accept.

Comment: @Bathsheba Actually, my comment doesn't cover the general case, it only applies to `assign`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's OK to copy the `nullptr` value to another pointer object, and that's all the implementation could possibly do. It's already forbidden to go past the end (defined here by beginning == end) or dereference it.

Comment: It's all you'd expect the implementation to do, perhaps, but if there were a precondition that an _InputIterator_ cannot be `nullptr`, an implementation would be free to assert or do some other crazy thing, and I don't think you've ruled that out.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Potatoswatter stated, C++ also made the expression `nullptr + 0` [valid](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/why-does-c-allow-arithmetic-on-null-poin/240001022). This wasn't the case in C.