# Conditionally initialize std::vector from pointer

Tags: c++, c++14

I am interfacing with some C++ code that has a method providing a pointer and object size (some proprietary library that I can't change). The interface looks something like this:

```
float *arrayPtr();
int arraySize();
```

I have a class that needs to copy this to a vector (in order to extend its lifetime). In the scenario where this pointer is not a nullptr, the constructor is fairly simple (I need to copy the data to extend its lifetime):

```
struct A {
    std::vector<float> vec;
    A(float *ptr, int size) : vec( ptr, std::next(ptr, size) ) {}
}
```

I am, however, a little unsure of how best to handle the initialization when `ptr` is a `nullptr`. I could default initialize, and then move everything to the constructor body, but that feels quite inefficient:

```
A(float *ptr, int size) {
    if (ptr) {
        vec = std::vector<float>( ptr, std::next(ptr, size));
    }
}
```

Are there any other alternatives?

When `ptr` is a `nullptr`, I would like the vector to just be default initialized to an empty vector.

EDIT:

It just occurred to me that I should probably be doing this:

```
A(float *ptr, int size) : vec( ptr ? std::vector<float>(ptr, std::next(ptr, size)) : std::vector<float>() ) {}
```

But perhaps there is a better form??

Comment: Assuming `size` is `0` in that case, I think it should work as-is?

Comment: @Quentin actually that is a good question, whether `vector<T>(null_ptr, std::next(null_ptr, 0))` is well-defined

Comment: Actually size is not reported as zero (I guess this is the reason that the code was seg faulting).

Comment: But that is handled easily enough

Comment: `but that feels quite inefficient` How about you measure it instead of "feeling"? First of all there's no way to avoid branching in your case (ergo unlikely you can improve performance noticably). Secondly unless you do billions iterations in a loop where you construct this `A` struct (in each step) it won't matter at all. Finally `I should probably be doing this:` what follows is sooooo unreadable and has no performance gain. Avoid one-liners.

Comment: @bremen_matt are you saying that the A was called with null pointer and non-zero size? It would be normal to regard that as the caller's responsibility  ; if you really did want to test for it you could throw an exception

Comment: Right. They were passing a nullptr with nonzero size.

Comment: I should say... this library was developed by a startup. Not that all startups are bad, but this one has tons of bugs... Copy/paste errors, incorrect sizes, etc.

Comment: @bremen_matt regarding performance, you have to compare those two. looks like premature optimization too me. But my advice is, you should ALWAYS check pointers if they are a nullptr. especially when you say the code is error prone... ALL input is evil!

Comment: @bremen_matt if passed size doesn't match the array's real size then there's no way you can detect this in general. `nullptr` is the only detectable case but there are infinitely uncovered cases here. And so this should be caller's responsibility.

Comment: @bremen_matt The code in your edit looks fine. I would have suggested that in an answer.

Comment: FWIW the original code looks fine. It's not "inefficient", plus it's simple and easy to read.

Answer (score 4):

This is not necessarily "better" (actually I think your original code is fine, since there is not really any cost to default initialization of a vector), but when you need to perform some logic for an initializer you can use a helper function:

```
struct A {
    std::vector<float> vec;
    A(float *ptr, int size) : vec( make_A_vector(ptr, size) ) {}

private:  
    static std::vector<float> make_A_vector(float const *begin, int size)
    {
        if ( size < 0 || (size > 0 && !begin) )
             throw std::runtime_error("invalid array length for A");

        if ( size == 0 )
             return {};

        return std::vector<float>(begin, begin + size);
   }
};
```

---

Another common design is to keep your class simple and have construction logic entirely in a free function:

```
struct A
{
    std::vector<float> vec;
};

inline A make_A(float const *ptr, int size)
{
     // sanity check omitted for brevity
     if ( size == 0 )
         return A{};

     return A{ std::vector<float>(ptr, ptr + size) };
}
```

It's an experience-based judgement call as to what would be overkill and what would be aesthetic :)

Answer (score 1):

Researching what `std::next` and the ctor of `std::vector` is doing. your first try works just fine. ONLY and ONLY if your `size` is reliably `0`, when your pointer is a `nullptr`.

[**`std::next(it, n)`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/next/)

> **it** - Iterator to base position. ForwardIterator shall be at least a
>   forward iterator.
>
> **n** - Number of element positions offset (1 by default).
>   This shall only be negative for random-access and bidirectional
>   iterators. difference_type is the numerical type that represents
>   distances between iterators of the ForwardIterator type.

If you are assured, your given size is `0`, when you get a `nullptr`, `std::next` returns the same position as your pointer points to.

[**`std::vector`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

You use this ctor:

> Constructs the container with the contents of the range [first, last).

If your `first` and `last` are the same, you get an empty `std::vector`. So the `nullptr` is never a problem.

---

Regardless this findings. you should ALWAYS check for `nullptr`'s. For the sake of defensive programming - ALL INPUT IS EVIL!

---

You mentioned, the library you get is known for being error prone. Please save yourself much troubles and check every parameter you get out of it of integrity.

---

One comment on your worries that your implementation would perform any worse then an other. Check those implementations in an `loop` with thousands or millions of iterations. Then you can make an prediction if it effects you.

Comment: Hmmm. [Is `nullptr` a valid _InputIterator_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853777/assign-with-nullptr-and-zero-size#comment104091236_21854125)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I did not find any undefined behavior if you do so. I discourage the OP anyway from doing so.

Comment: Well, if `nullptr` is not a valid _InputIterator_ then the constructor invocation we're all talking about has undefined behaviour, because it does not abide by the requirements.